# How to dynamically create a data set for Flot JS?

Tags: javascript, flot

I want to create a flot chart for an variable amount of trackers with an variable amount of trackable objects. My code seems to work so far, but I've noticed 2 anomalys.

If theres more than 1 value in:
**"var trackerList = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"];"**
it shows only the last value in the array.

If theres more than 1 value in:
**var registeredTrackableObjects = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];**
it shows nothing at all.

I've seen several examples, so I guess my code should work, what am I missing?
While I'm on it, what would be the best way to update that chart like once a second? I want to exchange the test value stuff with actual data from my java code.

Thanks.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () 
{ 
 //Test values
 var intensity = 5;
 var trackerList = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"];
 var registeredTrackableObjects = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];
 
 
 var xDistance = 1.05;//Distance between bars
 var yMin = 0;
 var yMax = 20;
 var xMin = 0;
 var xMax = 10;
 var data = [];//Flot JS format, which contains pairs of {label, array}
 var customBarArray = [];
 var customBar = [];

 //Create a data set for every TO
 for(i = 0; i<registeredTrackableObjects.length; i++)
 {
  //Create 1 bar for every tracker
  customBar = [];
  
  for(j = 0; j<trackerList.length; j++)
  {
   customBar[j] = j;
   customBar.push([xDistance * j, intensity]);
  }
  
  customBarArray.push(customBar);
  var name = "Beacon: " + i;
  data.push({label: name, data: customBarArray[i]});
  xDistance += 1.05;
 }

 
    $.plot($("#placeholder"), data, 
    {
        series: {
            bars: {
                show: true,
                barWidth: 0.1,
                lineWidth: 0,
                order: 1,
                fillColor: {
                    colors: [{
                        opacity: 1
                    }, {
                        opacity: 0.7
                    }]
                }
            }
        },
        xaxis: {
            mode: "time",
            min: xMin,
            max: xMax,
            tickLength: 0,
            tickSize: [1, "month"],
            axisLabel: 'Month',
            axisLabelUseCanvas: true,
            axisLabelFontSizePixels: 10,
            axisLabelFontFamily: 'Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, Tahoma, sans-serif',
            axisLabelPadding: 1
        },
        yaxis: {
            min: yMin,
            max: yMax,
            axisLabel: 'Value',
            axisLabelUseCanvas: true,
            axisLabelFontSizePixels: 10,
            axisLabelFontFamily: 'Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, Tahoma, sans-serif',
            axisLabelPadding: 5
        },
        legend: {
            backgroundColor: "#EEE",
            labelBoxBorderColor: "none"
        },
        colors: ["#AA4643", "#89A54E", "#4572A7"]
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it myself by now. Just remove `customBar[j] = j;` and it will work.